# How to setup a virtual environment for Python 3.6

Tags: python, django

I need to create a virtual environment to run Django with Python 3.6. Can anyone guide me how to execute it. I hear it is different from earlier versions.

Comment: What it is that you think is different? Did you stumble upon a problem doing that?

Comment: Yes, I was not able to install virtual wrapper using pip install. It was giving an error. I was wondering if it had anything to do with the version now.

Comment: Post the execution log please

Answer (score 1):

So basically nothing changed beside is not recommended to use the pyenv script as is deprecated 
the documentation has it all
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: I had seen in one of the website the need to use virtual wrapper. However, the pip installation for that for Python 3.6 was not working. However, from you documentation I came to learn that, it is not required. Thank you.